# Validate form on the angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-forms

I created my application using angular-cli.
I try to validate my form. It is in html file:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Create url-shortener</h1>
    <form [formGroup]="createUrlForm">
        <div class="form-group"
             [ngClass]="{'has-error':!createUrlForm.controls['full_url'].valid && createUrlForm.controls['full_url'].touched}">
            <label><b>Full url</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                   [formControl]="createUrlForm.controls['full_url']"
                   placeholder="Paste a link to shorten it">
            <div
                *ngIf="createUrlForm.controls['full_url'].hasError('required') && createUrlForm.controls['full_url'].touched"
                class="alert alert-danger">Input url.
            </div>
            <div
                *ngIf="createUrlForm.controls['full_url'].hasError('pattern') && createUrlForm.controls['full_url'].touched"
                class="alert alert-danger">Incorrect url.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="create(createUrlForm.value)"
                    [disabled]="!createUrlForm.valid">Shorten
            </button>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" [routerLink]="['/']">Back</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And created component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

import { Url } from "../shared/models/url.model";
import { UrlService } from "../shared/services/url.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-url',
  templateUrl: './create-url.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['create-url.component.scss']
})
export class CreateUrlComponent {

  createUrlForm: any;

  constructor(
      private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
      private urlService: UrlService) {
      this.createUrlForm = formBuilder.group({
      "url": ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('https?://.+')]]
    })
  }

  create(url: Url) {

  }

}
```

When I click on button I see an error in the console:
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined`

I looked for answers on stackoverflow, but cannot find. Anywhere I created the error and spend a lot of time.

Comment: Your form group doesn't have any control named "full_url".

Comment: Thanky very much. I didn't see because of inattention.